# Making a category menu with its subcategories getting data from DB and PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am willing to do a dropdown (or a list, it doesn't matter) with categories and subcategories getting directly the data from the database.

The order should be:

CATEGORY 1

-- Subcategory 1

-- Subcategory 2

-- Subcategory 3
-- ...

CATEGORY 2

-- Subcategory 1

-- ...

...

And so on even adding future categories and subcategories.

I am using MVC and this is my code this far:

View:

```
<?php foreach ( $datoCategorias as $categorias ) { ?>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="col btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <?php echo $categorias['NAME'] ?></button>
                    <div class=" col dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?controller=products&action=category&id="></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php       } ?>
```

Index.php:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "category") {
                $controller = new productos_controller();
                $controller->category();
            }
```

Controller:

```
function category() {
            $categorias = new productos_models();
            $datoCategorias=$categorias->get_categorias();
            require_once("views/products.php");
        }
```

Model:

```
public function get_categorias(){
            $categorias=$this->db->query("select * from CATEGORY;");
                while($listaCategorias=$categorias->fetch_assoc()){
                $this->cats[]=$listaCategorias;
            }
            return $this->cats;
        }
```

Database table CATEGORY:

| ID | NAME | PARENTCATEGORY |

| 1  | CAT1 | null |

| 2  | CAT2 | null |

| 3  | CAT3 | null |

| 4  | SUB1 | 1    |

| 5  | SUB1 | 2    |

The problem is: How I should do the foreach or foreach'es to make the result look like the order I said before because I only managed to show the category's name.

Comment: is this code igniter?

Comment: No. I did this using some examples I got and by myself. I didn't use any framework.